# Suspend and Shutdown not working in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: suspend, laptop, 15.10, shutdown

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 on a razer blade 14 2013 with kernel version 4.2. Everything is currently stock. Unfortunately, suspend (both doing it manually and closing the lid) as well as shut down do not seem to work correctly. In the case of shut down, the screen goes black, but the laptop is still on. In the case of suspend and closing the lid, the screen goes black, but I can't wake it up. If anyone has any advice that would be appreciated :D

Comment: Have you run `pm-is-supported`? See the `man` page for how.  Read up on the contents of the `pm-utils` package. Get a list with `dpkg -L pm-utils`

Comment: I have this problem with 15.10 on an Intel NUC DE3815TYKH. A work-around for me was to disable XHCI USB controllers in the BIOS...